# Matching a value in one column to the name of another column

Tags: r

I have a char column, where I need to match the value of that column to the name of other column in my data frame in order to extract the value from the other column. I have added a picture as I think it will be easier to understand.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing to extract the elements from the first dataset and create the 'result' column in 'd2'

```
d2$result <- d1[-1][cbind(1:nrow(d1), match(d2$mycol, names(d1)[-1]))]
d2
#  mycol result
#1     a     40
#2   bxb     88
#3   bxb     76
#4    ct     33
```

---

It could be also that there is a single dataset available i.e. 'd1' and want to get the 'd2'.  In that case, do a `melt` and `subset`

```
library(reshape2)
subset(melt(d1, id.var="mycol"), mycol==variable, select= c(1,3))
```

#### data

```
d1 <- data.frame(mycol = c("a", "bxb", "bxb", "ct"), a = c(40, 8, 43, 94), 
 `bxb` =c(7, 88, 76, 12), ct = c(4,6, 8954, 33), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
 check.names=FALSE) 
d2 <- data.frame(mycol = c('a', 'bxb', 'bxb', 'c'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```