# R: How to extract value name in a column and column name of another column if the row in the other column has a missing value

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm not sure how to word this, or if it's even possible, but the goal is to get the class name from column 1 and the column names for rows that have NA's

This is a snippet of some of the data:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Soybean)
Soybean <-  Soybean %>% as.data.frame(row.names = 1:nrow(.))
Soybean[c(32:39),]
              Class date plant.stand precip temp hail crop.hist area.dam sever seed.tmt germ
32 phytophthora-rot    1           1      2    1 <NA>         3        1  <NA>     <NA> <NA>
33 phytophthora-rot    2           1      2    2 <NA>         2        1  <NA>     <NA> <NA>
34 phytophthora-rot    1           1      2    0    0         2        1     2        1    1
35 phytophthora-rot    2           1      2    2 <NA>         2        1  <NA>     <NA> <NA>
36 phytophthora-rot    3           1      2    1 <NA>         2        1  <NA>     <NA> <NA>
37 phytophthora-rot    0           1      1    1    0         1        1     1        0    0
38 phytophthora-rot    3           1      2    0    0         2        1     2        1    1
39 phytophthora-rot    2           1      1    1 <NA>         0        1  <NA>     <NA> <NA>
```

Desired:

```
32 phytophthora-rot  hail 
32 phytophthora-rot  server
32 phytophthora-rot  seed.tmt 
32 phytophthora-rot  germ
33 phytophthora-rot  hail
33 phytophthora-rot  sever
33 phytophthora-rot  seed.tmt 
33 phytophthora-rot  germ
39 phytophthora-rot  hail
39 phytophthora-rot  server
```

and so on. **The ultimate goal is to see if the predictors with missing values are related to the class they're in.**

I have used

```
library(visdat)
vis_miss(Soybean)
```

but this just gives an overview of the missing data without providing the class names and the associated predictor with the missing data.
I also saw advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636386/matching-a-value-in-one-column-to-the-name-of-another-column), but it seems to be making the assumption that I know what all the desired values are.

Answer (score 0):

```
soybean %>% pivot_longer(-Class, names_to = "with_na" , values_to ="values") %>% filter(is.na(values)) %>% select (Class, with_na)
```

I didn't get to run the code but let me know if it didn't work, good luck

Comment: Hi there! Do you know which package with_na is in? I tried dplyr, but it says `object 'with_na' not found`

Comment: @bandcar you should have `names_to = 'with_na', values_to = 'values'` for it to work

Comment: You should have names and not symbols. Check my comment above

Comment: Thanks, forgot the quotation marks, will edit.

Comment: The new error is: `Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't combine `date` <factor<cf72a>> and `plant.stand` <ordered<8fa51>>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: I see now the data types are not just numeric.
run the following line before the other code to change factors to numeric values

soybean %>% mutate(across(-Class, ~as.numeric(as.character(.x))))